# Linode - Centos 5.5 -

Tags: centos5

I rather foolishly undertook to install a control panel on a Linode.

I opted to use CentOs 5.5 (either ordinary or 64 bit)

but I am like a monkey playing a reward game...

I have some idea of what I am doing, but not enough....

In certain areas I am hopeless....do I install Webmin/virtualmin, or ISP Config.....

ISP Config 2 or 3?

I would employ someone to help, but how do i find the right person?

Where can i learn the ropes on all this?
There seems to be no systematic training, and 
even when I try to research college courses in the UK, I am none the wiser as to where I could go to learn how to run a Linux server.

Has anyone any pointers?

Right now I am looking at the security aspects of the server... rkhunter , denyhosts etc...

Any advice on installing and maintaining these things?

Answer (score 1):

Although cpanel costs $$, it work all the trouble you have to go through with the other control panels, unless ofcourse you are experienced enough to setup/fix things. Also try a fully managed provider, you could use some help on and off. linode is awesome, but unmanaged.